# Devise forgot password throws ArgumentError in Devise::PasswordsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Initially, I was having this issue only on my heroku app, but after updating the devise gem to 2.2.4, I have the issue on my localhost as well.

My main concern is that I am getting this error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:58:in `reset_password_instructions'
```

I've updated the devise gem to

```
devise (2.2.4)
```

And I am running:

```
Rails 3.2.11
```

My development.rb initializer has the following host:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

This is where line 58 starts in my user_mailer.rb file:

```
def reset_password_instructions(user)
  devise_mail(user, :reset_password_instructions)
end
```

My question is, why am I sending two arguments?  It should only be sending in the e-mail address as defined in my devise/passwords/new.html.erb file:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for(resource, :html => {:class => "form-signin", :method => :post}, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <h2 class = "form-signin-heading">Forgot your password?</h2>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :type => "text", :class =>"input-block-level", :placeholder => "Email Address" %>
    <%= f.submit "Send me reset password instructions", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    </br>
    </br>
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
My reset_password_instructions.html.erb file is here:

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>
<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.</p>
<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token =>@resource.reset_password_token) %></p>
<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

Can anyone spot an issue?

Comment: Do you have a `views/user_mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb` template?

Comment: d_ethier, just added the reset_password_instructions.html.erb file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the answer was quite simple, I had to follow the upgrading instructions from devise.  For anyone running into this problem, the upgrade to Devise 2.2 can be found on [Devise 2.2 upgrade instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.2)

Edit:

The upgrade documentation for Devise includes instructions to modify methods with an options block. To fix this issue you need to re-define the `reset_password_instructions` method as follows (note, the default is to use `record` in place of `user` but this specific example uses `user`):

```
def reset_password_instructions(user, opts={})
  ...
end
```

Comment: I'm going to assume it was `def reset_password_instructions(user, opts={})`. It's generally better to include the answer as opposed to a link to a guide. Thanks for updating though.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it.  Do you mind editing the answer with it so you get credit as well.